# How to set histogram color as a gradient?

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

Below are two plots, of which I seek to reproduce the one on the *left*. The plot was produced in Spyder 3.3.6 - however, so was one on the right; i.e., I can no longer reproduce the plot. I used the same code both times - a simple `plt.hist(bins=...)` on some data - a minimal variant below. Tested w/ Inline, Automatic, Qt5, and Tkinter graphical backends, w/ 76.0 dpi - though I do not recall all other settings, which may have differed at the time.

How do I get histograms to look like the one on the left - a "looping gradient"?

[image]

---

**Environ. info**: Win-10 OS, GTX 1070, Spyder 3.3.6, Python 3.7.5, IPython 7.10.1, Matplotlib 3.1.1

---

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2)
x = 0.06*(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 4000) + 0.05*np.random.randn(4000))

plt.hist(x, bins=400)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 1.2)
plt.box(None)
```

**Tip**: the default matplotlib blue is `color=[0.121569, 0.466667, 0.705882]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more complete answer w/ an explanation relative to @An0ther0ne's follows, but thanks to OP for showing the core of the method.

The idea is to fetch individual histogram bars, `patches`, and set their color via `.set_facecolor()` according to a gradient color scheme. We can generate such a scheme as a sine function centered about some "main color" to yield desired effect; matplotlib's default color, `[0.121569, 0.466667, 0.705882]`, shall be used.

Lastly, `bins_norm = bins / bins.max()` normalizes `bins` to lie between `-1` and `1`, hence spanning twice the sinusoidal period, so we'll be using `np.pi` instead of `2*np.pi` in `np.sin()`.

---

**Example**:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2)
x = 0.06*(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 8000) + 0.05*np.random.randn(8000))

pretty_hist(x, 400, n_loops=8,  alpha=0.9)
pretty_hist(x, 400, n_loops=16, alpha=1)
```

[image]

---

**Function**:

```py
def pretty_hist(data, bins, n_loops=8, alpha=1, base_color=[0.121569, 0.466667, 0.705882]): 
    N, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, bins=bins, density=True)
    bm = bins.max()
    bins_norm = bins / bm
    bc = base_color

    for bin_norm, patch in zip(bins_norm, patches):
        grad = np.sin(np.pi * n_loops * bin_norm) / 15 + .04 
        color = (bc[0] + grad, bc[1] + grad, bc[2] + grad, alpha)
        patch.set_facecolor(color)

    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 1)
    plt.box(None)
    plt.show()
```

---

**Introspection**: we can see what `grad` is doing by recording it at each iteration and then plotting; for `n_loops=8` and `bins=400`:

```py
grads = []
bin_norm, patch in zip(bins_norm, patches):
        grad = np.sin(np.pi * n_loops * bin_norm) / 15 + .04
        grads.append(grad)
plt.plot(grads)
```

[image]

Comment: Wasn't the question what settings you might have changed that caused this?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest No, just anything to get the histograms to look like one on the left - settings or Pyplot inclusive. Latter's surely preferable, and was found - though I couldn't find a color combination to make it look exactly the same, it's close enough, and maybe even better.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest For the record, regarding my other question, just installed Spyder 4 - and with same settings and mpl commands, all plot qualities are surreally superior; it's like SVG, but is PNG. Thus, graphical backend & related under-the-hood stuff may in fact be the culprit, independent of matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
np.random.seed(2)
x = 0.06*(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 4000) + 0.05*np.random.randn(4000))
N, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, bins=400, density=True)
bm = bins.max()
fracs = bins / bm
for thisfrac, thispatch in zip(fracs, patches):
    Green = np.abs(np.sin(thisfrac/bm)/2)
    color = (0,Green,1,1)
    thispatch.set_facecolor(color)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 1.2)
plt.box(None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, you've got the root of the method - though, it isn't quite the same blue; the default matplotlib blue I seek is `color=[0.121569, 0.466667, 0.705882]` - if you edited your answer to produce the colors in the question, that'd work best

Comment: Also some explanation wouldn't harm

Comment: Wrote my own as there's a fair deal of info to unpack, and it should cover the explaining portion - nonetheless, upvoted your answer